# Is this an abuse of notation? ("Complex Analysis" by Kunihiko Kodaira.)

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I am reading "Complex Analysis" by Kunihiko Kodaira.

Kodaira said $c$ is an accumulation point of $D$ in the Definition 1.1.
And he said "if $\lim_{z\to c} f(z) = f(c)$, then $f(z)$ is said to be continuous at $c$.".

So, of course, I thought $c$ was an accumulation point of $D$ in $\lim_{z\to c} f(z) = f(c)$.
But he said "if $c$ is an isolated point of $D$, then for sufficiently small $\delta$ the only $z$ satisfying $z\in D$ and $|z-c| < \delta(\epsilon)$ is $c$, in which case $f(z)$ is certainly continuous at $c$.".

Is this an abuse of notation?

[image]

Comment: I think you're right, limits are only defined in relation to accumulation points. But continuity is defined by limit, in accumulation point, and by convention, in isolated point.

Comment: @enzotib Thank you very much for your comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, indeed it's conventional to define $\lim_{z \to c} f(z)$ only if $c$ is an accumulation point (or rather limit point) of the domain $D$, and your text does so.

But it's rather inelegant to define continuity in terms of limits for *all* $c \in D$, even if $c$ is not an accumulation point. If you want to use the metric just **define** continuity the standard $\varepsilon$, $\delta$ way as in the final equation of your quote, and then *prove* the following two facts:

> If $f$ is a function on $D$ and $c \in D$ and $c \in D'$ then $\lim_{z \to c} f(z) = f(c)$ iff $f$ is continuous in $c$.

> If $f$ is a function on $D$ and $c \in D$ is isolated in $D$, then $f$ is continuous in $c$.

This seems more elegant to me, and avoids the mentioned issues.

Comment: Henno Brandsma, Thank you very much for your answer.